# How to replace with only the part before the ":" in every row of a column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

so in a dataset, I have a column named "Interventions", and each row looks like this:

**row1**: "Drug: Rituximab|Drug: Utomilumab|Drug: Avelumab|Drug: PF04518600"

**row2**: "Biological: alemtuzumab|Biological: donor lymphocytes|Drug: carmustine|Drug: cytarabine|Drug: etoposide|Drug: melphalan|Procedure: allogeneic bone marroow"

I want to only extract the *Intervention type* such as "Drug", "Biological", "Procedure" to remain in the column. And even better, if can only have the unique Intervention type instead of "Drug" 4 times like the first row.

The expected output would look like this:

**row1**: "Drug"

**row2**: "Biological, Drug, Procedure"

I am just getting started with r, I have **tidyverse** installed and kinda used to playing with the **%>%**. If anyone can help me with this, much appreciated !

Comment: expected output would be for row1: "Drug" ; row2: "Biological, Drug, Procedure" .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to extract only the prefix part before the `:`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(Interventions = map_chr(str_extract_all(Interventions, 
          "\\w+(?=:)"), ~ toString(sort(unique(.x)))))
#               Interventions
#1                        Drug
#2 Biological, Drug, Procedure
```

---

Or another option is to separate the rows based on the delimiters, `slice` the alternate rows and `paste` together the `sort`ed `unique` values in 'Interventions'

```
df1 %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
   separate_rows(Interventions, sep="[:|]") %>% 
   group_by(rn) %>% 
   slice(seq(1, n(), by = 2)) %>%
   distinct() %>%
   summarise(Interventions = toString(sort(unique(Interventions)))) %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   select(-rn)
# A tibble: 2 x 1
#    Interventions              
#  <chr>                      
#1 Drug                       
#2 Biological, Drug, Procedure
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Interventions = c("Drug: Rituximab|Drug: Utomilumab|Drug: Avelumab|Drug: PF04518600", 
"Biological: alemtuzumab|Biological: donor lymphocytes|Drug: carmustine|Drug: cytarabine|Drug: etoposide|Drug: melphalan|Procedure: allogeneic bone marroow"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply, however, since it is only two examples of the data in this single column, there are more Intervention types than these three. And originally, each row of the dataset represent a unique clinical trial. So I don't need the specific drug's name here, only the Type of the Interventions, and I was hoping for them to be in the same row.

Answer (score 1):

Not as concise and the same logic as Akruns but in Base R:

```
# Create df: 

df1 <- structure(list(Interventions = c("Drug: Rituximab|Drug: Utomilumab|Drug: Avelumab|Drug: PF04518600", 
                                        "Biological: alemtuzumab|Biological: donor lymphocytes|Drug: carmustine|Drug: cytarabine|Drug: etoposide|Drug: melphalan|Procedure: allogeneic bone marroow"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

# Assign a row id vec: 

df1$row_num <- 1:nrow(df1)

# Split string on | delim: 

split_up <- strsplit(df1$Interventions, split = "[|]")

# Roll down the dataframe - keep uniques: 

rolled_out <- unique(data.frame(row_num = rep(df1$row_num, sapply(split_up, length)),

                             Interventions = gsub("[:].*","", unlist(split_up))))

# Stack the dataframe: 

df2 <- aggregate(Interventions~row_num, rolled_out, paste0, collapse = ", ")

# Drop id vec: 

df2 <- within(df2, rm("row_num"))
```